# AMD GPU driver install problems!

Tags: drivers, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

Ubuntu MATE 20.04.3 LTS
6600XT GPU

replacing my old gpu with a new one and having a real hurdle.

downloaded the proper 21.40.2 for ubuntu 20.04.3 file [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6600-series/amd-radeon-rx-6600-xt)

Followed directions [here](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-prereq.html)

even got the pro package from [here and followed the extraction method](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-643)

ran update, upgrade distro, reboot, and.... nothing.  Plugging hdmi into gpu doesn't output video.

i checked software & updates and proprietary drivers are checked, when i check additional drivers, it shows nothing.

running

```
  lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
```

shows that the system recognizes i have the proper gpu in place

running

```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

returns nothing

running amdgpu-install and amdgpu-pro-install output:

```
  user@user-LinuxDesktop:~/Desktop/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04$ ./amdgpu-install -y
  [sudo] password for user: 
  deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
  Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
  Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
  Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
  Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
  Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
  Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
  Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
  Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
  Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Hit:8 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.40.2/ubuntu focal InRelease            
  Hit:9 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/4.5.2 ubuntu InRelease                  
  Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
  Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Reading package lists... Done                 
  The amdgpu driver is already installed or was not uninstalled correctly.
  Please fully uninstall the driver before proceeding with installation
  You can try running the amdgpu-uninstall or amdgpu-pro-uninstall script 
  present in /usr/bin to clean up the previous installation
  user@user-LinuxDesktop:~/Desktop/amdgpu-pro-20.20-1098277-ubuntu-20.04$ ./amdgpu-pro-install -y
  deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
  Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
  Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease       
  Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B] 
  Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
  Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg            
  Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg       
  Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease 
  Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
  Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
  Hit:7 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/21.40.2/ubuntu focal InRelease            
  Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
  Hit:10 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/4.5.2 ubuntu InRelease                 
  Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Reading package lists... Done
  The amdgpu driver is already installed or was not uninstalled correctly.
  Please fully uninstall the driver before proceeding with installation
  You can try running the amdgpu-uninstall or amdgpu-pro-uninstall script present in /usr/bin to clean up the previous installation
```

but when i check with dpkg -l amdgpu amdgpu is confirmed but amdgpu-pro is not.

i've updated and upgraded and rebooted and i can't get the gpu to activate and it still does not show up under additional drivers.

any thoughts?

Comment: AFIAK the GPU you have doesn't need any additional drivers. Were you having problems before you started?

Comment: my old GPU straight up died on me.

but yeah, plugging hdmi doesn't carry out video.

Edit: gpu works fine on windows partition.

Comment: What kind of GPU did you have before? Best practice with new hardware is to reinstall the OS, especially if the hardware is very different.

Comment: AMD - RX470 

You think i'm just better off reinstalling the entire OS?  Im asking because I like staying on the LTS versions.

Comment: Maybe run a live session (Try Ubuntu from installation media). If everything works correctly in the live session, I'd consider a reinstall. You can try/install 20.04 which is the most recent LTS.

Comment: I'm currently on 20.04.3 LTS.

should i try reinstalling that version anyway?

Comment: If everything works well in the live session, that's what I would do if I were in your position. 20.04.3 is the same release as 20.04, it's just that LTS releases occasionally get "point releases" to consolidate updates, so you will have less to update by installing the most recent point release.

Comment: is the kernel up to date enough on 20.04.3 that it would take care of this issue?

Comment: I believe that the HWE kernel is the default for 20.04.3, so it should be fine.  The "Try Ubuntu" live session will give you the opportunity to see if everything is working before you make a commitment to (re)install. See: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle

Comment: I think i'm just going to go with a reinstall.  tried upgrading on current install and it didn't do anything for 21.

live session outputs video on both.

Comment: May be it's too late to comment on your question - however: (1) I have the `amdgpu-pro` and it's not in the `Additional Drivers` dialog (2) The output message you presented above asked you to uninstall the amdgpu-pro at first - did you do that? (3) The command to look for packages is `dpkg -l | grep amdgpu`, but not the `dpkg -l amdgpu`.

Comment: @HEKTO - thanks for the reply.  Hate to admit it bc i don't see this as a solution but I just ended up installing the newest version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my setup. Maybe this will help someone else.

OS: **Ubuntu 20.04** (dual boot) **Ubuntu Studio 21.04**

Board: **ASUS Tuf Gaming B550M-Plus**

CPU: **AMD Ryzen 9 5900x 12-Core, 24-Thread**

RAM: Corsair Vengeance 2x32GB **CMK64GX4M2D3600C18**

Graphics: **XFX Radeon RX 6600XT**

If you already have a previous version or prior failed attempt

```
amdgpu-uninstall -y
```

**MANDATORY** Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Update and Install some packages

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install git clinfo darktable -y
```

Make an (optional) AMD directory

```
mkdir amd
```

git clone firmware

```
cd amd && git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git && cd
```

Copy over the firmware

```
sudo cp ~/amd/linux-firmware/amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu && sudo update-initramfs -k all -u -v && sudo apt update
```

Get the recent [AMD Driver for Radeon RX 6600xt](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6600-series/amd-radeon-rx-6600-xt)

```
wget -P ~/amd/ https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/21.50.2/ubuntu/focal/amdgpu-install_21.50.2.50002-1_all.deb
```

Install the file you just downloaded

```
cd amd && sudo apt install -y ./amdgpu-install_21.50.2.50002-1_all.deb && cd && sudo apt update
```

Install the driver (check optional --flags for your use case)

```
amdgpu-install -y --accept-eula --opencl=rocr,legacy --usecase=graphics,opencl
```

Add yourself to the Video and Render groups

```
sudo apt update && sudo usermod -aG video $USER && sudo usermod -aG render $USER
```

**MANDATORY** Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

After reboot, run:

```
clinfo -l
```

or more verbose

```
clinfo
```

Checkout Darktable as well

```
darktable-cltest
```

Good talk.